# Counting directories on UNIX

Tags: bash, unix

I need a bash script that can count directories that are inside other directories on a FreeBSD.
The case is like this:
The path is `home/myuser/direct` than inside this directory there are like 20 directories named only by one letter like A B C D E F and so on. Inside every A directory, B directory there are many other directories with different names, such as mydirectory1, mydirectory2 and so on. Inside mydirectory1 there are differnet files and directories, and I need to count only the directories that are under the mydirectory1, and not the files. I came up with this, but using this, I will have to do that manually for each directory:

```
home/myuser/direct# ls -l A/* | grep ^d | wc -l
```

than for the B directory I will have to:

```
home/myuser/direct# ls -l B/* | grep ^d | wc -l
```

and so on. Is there a way, to automatically do this, I mean change the letter A to B and so on?

P.S, sorry about the confusion as English is not my first language :(

Comment: Why are you running as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes you want the number of subfolders for each folder in the current directory. If you want to sum them all up into one value, that is a different question... It is not *incredibly* robust to variations in folder names, but should work for most cases when there is not strange punctuation:

```
for D in */; do echo "$D": $(ls -d "$D"*/| wc -l); done
```

Example output:

```
DATA/: 14
LOGS/: 2
PLOTS/: 3
SCRIPTS/: 2
ls: libraries//*/: No such file or directory
libraries/: 0
```

Here is a version which suppresses the error for empty folders:

```
for D in */; do echo "$D": $(ls -d "$D"*/ 2>/dev/null |wc -l); done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
find * -type d -print | wc -l
```

Comment: Tried that, got this:
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f file] [file ...] [expression]

Comment: @Big_M help to someone is possible ONLY if he knows at least basics about we talking... If you can't manage one usage string - simply isn't possible to help...

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice, however, the reason coming here is ONLY because I did not know how to do that!

Comment: @Big_M, do you have a file in the current directory whose name begins with a `-`?

Comment: No, on the current directory (home/myuser/direct), I only have directories named with single letters.